# Android Java: Too many imageviews?

Tags: java, android, arrays, imageview

I have an arraylist of 50 imageviews containing the same bitmap using this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
        imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
        imageViews.add(imageView);
        view.addView(imageView);


    }
```

This code does not cause lag except for when I move each one:

```
final Runnable bulletData2 = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
   if(i=0;i<=50;i++){
      movex = Math.cos((imageViews.get(i).getRotation() - 90) * Math.PI / 180) * 32;
      movey = Math.sin((imageViews.get(i).getRotation() - 90)* Math.PI / 180) * 32;
      imageViews.get(i).setX((float) (imageViews.get(i).getX() + movex));
      imageViews.get(i).setY((float) (imageViews.get(i).getY() + movey));
   }
 handler2.postDelayed(this, 2);    

 }
};
```

The bitmap is only 6kB and I tried a 600 byte version of the bitmap and it still lags.

If I set the imageviews to invisible then there is no lag, and if the images overlap and the app runs fast.

I have tried adding hardware acceleration and largeheap but I only see a slight difference.

Could anyone let me know what I should change?

Edit: Imageviews is an arraylist, and view is a viewgroup = my frameLayout

Comment: Try to use ListVew with Item contain single ImageView.

Comment: why calculte the movex and movey when  you dont even use it

Comment: Could you explain with code Haresh? And I use it to move the imageviews by their angle of rotation which changes dynamically

Comment: You will be suprised how easy you can do it without ImageViews only by drawing Bitmaps by yourself,  its gonna be much faster too

Comment: I didn't think you could move a bitmap without an imageview, could you show me how?

Comment: You need a class extending View, in onDraw call Canvas.drawBitmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are updating the 50 ImageViews position every 2 millisecond which is incredibly fast that android have trouble rendering at that fast rate and causes lag on your device.

**solution:**

Increase the delay of your handler and calculate the `movex` and `movey` on a separate thread and update the imageView's position in the main thread to prevent exception.

Comment: Ive tried changing the milliseconds but it starts to get choppy around >25, but what do you mean in the main thread?

Comment: You're definitely right though, the lag was coming from the 2 millisecond update

Comment: @user3705120 and increase the update 50 will suffice.